# how to fix setPayloadJSON error in wso2 ei

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to remove an element of a request json payload before sending to the back end, I tried to delete the required parameter in javascript meditator in wso2 ei, When i run the API, i get following error,

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: mc.setPaylodJSON is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:426)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.access$300(NashornScriptEngine.java:73)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:514)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:394)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:289)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:261)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:351)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: <eval>:1 TypeError: mc.setPaylodJSON is not a function
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:213)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:185)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:172)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookup(Undefined.java:102)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:106)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
        at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
        at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
        at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
        at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
        at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:421)
        ... 24 more
```

My js code is as follows,

```
var requestPayload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
delete requestPayload.user.name;
mc.setPaylodJSON(requestPayload);
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo in your code: try mc.setPayload(requestPayload)  (notice the "a" !)

Comment: Hi, I've moved the above comment to an answer. In case you agree, can you mark it as accepted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code: try mc.setPayload(requestPayload) (notice the "a" !)